# How to clear symfony form validation error on click inside field having error

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

Can someone tell me how I can clear a symfony2 field error when you click inside the field having that error ?

Thanks

Comment: That's a client-side UI-issue. Symfony won't help you here. To start, you'll need to use javascript to remove the error-message and/or any applied css classes. This though, depends largely on the rendered form-html.

Answer (score 2):

As said by @Yoshi use js. if you have one field you want to do this for simply do this:

```
$("#id_of_field").on("click", function(){
   document.getElementById("id_of_field").value = ""; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, what about there are multiple fields, how can remove it only for the field you clicked inside it?

Comment: What you can do is use class for this, basically you add the same class to the fields, Tell JS to check all when clicked upon. And then when they contain error wipe that certain field.